# Html.DropDownList in asp.net Core 2.0 create extra first item

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to use Html.DropDownList and select the value based on querystring:

```
@{
    var collectionStatusSelections = new List<SelectListItem>();
    collectionStatusSelections.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Pending", Text = "Pending" });
    collectionStatusSelections.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Collected", Text = "Collected" });
}

@Html.DropDownList("collectionStatus", collectionStatusSelections, Context.Request.Query["collectionStatus"].ToString());
```

However whatever the value in the querystring is added to the first item in the generated HTML `<select>`. (e.g, "?collectionStatus=AAA" will add "AAA")

[HTML.Dropdown document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.dropdownlist?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

optionLabel

String

The text for a default empty item. Does not include such an item if argument is null.

Comment: Your question is confusing, and doesn’t seem to ask anything.  What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to include a default text when the querystring is not present, then put a check for null and use a default string if true.

```
@Html.DropDownList("collectionStatus", collectionStatusSelections, Context.Request.Query["collectionStatus"].ToString() ?? “Default”);
```